# Can I change Internet Explorer security settings using a script?

Tags: batch-file, internet-explorer, vbscript

Is it possible to change Internet Explorer security settings using a .bat or .vbs file?

Basically, I need to change IE7 and IE8 security settings for the local intranet.  The settings I want to change are:

```
Display video and animation on a webpage that does not use external media player
Doanload signed ActiveX controls
Download unsighned ActiveX controls
Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting
```

These should be set to `Enable`

I don't know how to use Group Policies but we have network software which allows me to specify the location of a .bat/vbs file and run it on all computers in the network.

Answer (score 4):

You could accomplish this using registry hacks in your batch files, but GPO would be the appropriate and best way to go.  With a GPO, you can control the the settings from being changed back by a user or rougue website.  GPOs will apply every hour and 1/2 or so in most environments, whereas your scripts (I'm guessing) are more manual in nature.

Here's a good MSKB on the registry keys you can look at:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569

another KB for writing the batch files:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727154.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can edit the registry with a batch file.  For example:

```
@echo off
SET COREDB=CoreDB_DB
SET INSTANCE=
@echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00>CoreDB.reg
@echo.>>CoreDB.reg
@echo [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources]>>CoreDB.reg
@echo "%COREDB%"="SQL Server">>CoreDB.reg
@echo [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\%COREDB%]>>CoreDB.reg
@echo "Driver"="%SYSTEMDRIVE%\\WINDOWS\\system32\\sqlsrv32.dll">>CoreDB.reg
@echo "Server"="%COMPUTERNAME%%INSTANCE%">>CoreDB.reg
@echo "Database"="%COREDB%">>CoreDB.reg
@echo "Trusted_Connection"="Yes">>CoreDB.reg

@echo [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources]>>CoreDB.reg
@echo "%COREDB%"="SQL Server">>CoreDB.reg
@echo [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\%COREDB%]>>CoreDB.reg
@echo "Driver"="%SYSTEMDRIVE%\\WINDOWS\\system32\\sqlsrv32.dll">>CoreDB.reg
@echo "Server"="%COMPUTERNAME%INSTANCE%">>CoreDB.reg
@echo "Database"="%COREDB%">>CoreDB.reg
@echo "Trusted_Connection"="Yes">>CoreDB.reg

regedit /s CoreDB.reg
```

Comment: You should check out the [`reg.exe` command](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html). It can manipulate the registry directly without the need to create an intermediate .REG file.